# Exporting stored procedure from SQL Server 2012

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want to export some selected stored procedure from SQL Server 2012 frequently.
Is there any option to export those selected stored procedures in a single click or query without again selecting them all?

Comment: You want to script the SP's or just backup the database, and save them that way.

Comment: i want to save all  the selected SP's as a single file,Like we exporting.